# Hitarea in LinearLayout view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have defined a LinearLayout with some TextView's spread out. 
Instead of putting a setOnTouchListener on each specific TextView, I like to divide my LinearLayout in three areas (hitareas).
If I hit the top area I do something (in the middle something else etc.).
I.e. I'd like to have three listeners for top, middle and bottom and in each area I have
any number of Android TextView's (or possible other widgets) laid out.

How can I solve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one OnTouchListener and get the coordinates from the MotionEvent with [getX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX%28%29) or [getY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY%28%29) and calculate which third of the LinearLayout they touched.

Comment: Thanks! Combined it with v.getHeight() in onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)